# Trying to connect Mysql data base to ipython environment in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, data-analysis

Encountered below error message

```
MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

please way out please

I was expecting it to run and import my Mysql database as called up

Comment: It might help to see the code that produced this error.